# Running python script from django views

Tags: python, django

Want to run a python script from django views. And I dont want to wait till the script execution. The python script should do its work in the background and in the meanwhile, I will send response to the client that "the script is running in the background". Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` is best if you want to send immediate response. But make sure that *`subprocess.Popen`* is not returning any value back. i.e., you have to use like below:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python","test.py"], close_fds=True)
```

And use close_fds=True along with that, also helps better.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you say "do it in the background" I'm going to suggest [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) . It involves running RabbitMQ as a local daemon that Celery uses as a intermediate data-store and [Django can ask Celery to perform tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

If you need to track status, once you add a task, you can get a UUID for it and then query Celery for the status, and/or just have Celery stick the result in the standard Django ORM for you that you poll (or use webhooks, or whatever it is hipsters are using these days).

---

That is, of course, a lot of learning and a fair amount of ongoing burden for just running something in the background. You can just [do it the dirty `subprocess.Popen` way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224186/12870). You won't capture any output or get any status... But it should just about work.